# Combine D3 node and HTML

Tags: leaflet, html, svg, d3

I followed [this](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/11602fac1ea66c2a6d7f78067b2deddb) example of putting a d3 graph in a leaflet popup. The code returns with div.node(). What exactly is a node? I would like the Leaflet Popup To display this custom HTML, and then have the d3 chart below it:

```
var content = '<h1 id = "popUpHeader">'+feature.properties.SubDivName+'</h1>' + document.getElementById("sasi").innerHTML + document.getElementById("chart")
```

I'd like to keep the chart() function separate from this HTML. But when I try and combine the output from the chart function and this bit of HTML, the d3 chart does not display. How can I get the chart() function to return my D3 graph as just another HTML element I can append to my 'content' variable?

```js
    <script>

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // parse the date / time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      // format the data
      data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.date = parseTime(d.date);
          d.close = +d.close;
      });

      // Scale the range of the data
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

      // Add the valueline path.
      svg.append("path")
          .data([data])
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", valueline);

      // Add the X Axis
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // Add the Y Axis
      svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    });
        return div.node();
    }
```

If I do this:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
  var content = '<h1 id = "popUpHeader">' + 
    feature.properties.SubDivName+'</h1>' +
    document.getElementById("sasi").innerHTML + 
    document.getElementById("chart") + 
    '<p>name: ' + feature.properties.f2 + '</p>');
  layer.bindPopup(content+chart);
}
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this statement:

```js
layer.bindPopup(content+chart);
```

The `+` operator concatenates strings. Thus you are coercing the function `chart` to a string and then you are concatenating it with the string in the variable `content`.

To solve this, you must pass the `feature` to the `chart` function and evaluate it (not tested):

```js
layer.bindPopup(content+chart(feature))
```

PS.: As per the `D3 documentation`, `div.node()` simply returns the first element of the `div` selection.

Comment: when I do this, I get the chart is just displaying as [object HTMLDivElement]. That is it is displaying text that says that, and not the actual graph

Comment: What if you try `layer.bindPopup(content+chart(feature).innerText)`?

Comment: this also did not work for me, when I do that the chart does not show up

Comment: What you put into `bindPopup()` must be one of `<String|HTMLElement|Function|Popup>`. Make sure that you can display the chart inside the popup and fiddle with the heading later.